# how to redirect to a page in php?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, header

I have the following PHP file

```
<?php
//Load the database configuration file
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "*****", "*****", 'kkVoting');
//Convert JSON data into PHP variable
$userData = json_decode($_POST['userData']);
if (!empty($userData)) {
    $oauth_provider = $_POST['oauth_provider'];
    //Check whether user data already exists in database
    $prevQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."' AND oauth_uid = '".$userData ->id."' AND status = 1";
    $prevResult = $db ->query($prevQuery);
    if ($prevResult ->num_rows > 0) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("hello");
        window.location = "end.php"
        </script >;
    } else {
        //Insert user data
        $query = "INSERT INTO users SET oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."', oauth_uid = '".$userData ->id."', first_name = '".$userData ->first_name."', last_name = '".$userData ->last_name."', email = '".$userData ->email."', gender = '".$userData ->gender."', locale = '".$userData ->locale."', picture = '".$userData ->picture ->data ->url."', link = '".$userData ->link."', created = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', modified = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', status=0";
        $insert = $db ->query($query);
    }
}
?>
```

A JSON object is passed from an HTML file and it is being inserted into the database here. I want to redirect to another page if the entry already exists (and its status is 1). Is there a way to redirect to end.php inside the if{}.

echo js doesn't work. Header("Location: end.php"); also does not work.

I don't have much experience in PHP. But, I think echo js doesn't work because it is not an HTML file.

Please help.

Comment: why `header("Location: /end.php");` is not working ? did you send the response already ?

Comment: You are missing a closing speech mark, the colouring of the text should give it away.

Comment: Also note that you are using POST values directly in your SQL query, this is a *huge* security risk, please read http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @MCMXCII Yeah, that's true if OP is using an IDE or something like Notepad++, but you don't know OP's development set up.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yeah that's true, but I meant the colouring on here.

Comment: @MCMXCII Maybe PHP syntax highlighting doesn't work for me on here, does it for you? The only coloring I see is comments and some keywords like `new`.

Comment: @Tareq it doesn't. This is the whole php file. I have not sent a response.

Comment: @MCMXCII that was a typo that happened here. Not present in the original file.